# Import Excel to SQL Server with Insert and Update Using Entity Framework

Tags: excel, insert, entity

I have an excel file and I want to import the excel file basing on the existing database table using entity framework. Right now I firstly convert the excel sheet to a DataTable and have a loop to loop through each row of the DataTable. Each row has an id field and if the id exists in the database table I need to update it otherwise I need to insert this row to the database table. I want to use entity framework to wrap my loop into one transaction for roll back purpose in case of error. But I run into a scenario of two rows with the same id but different values. The first row is checked and added my entity collection, but the second row might be mistakenly updated the firstly added row because the firstly is not actually added due to the delayed context.SaveChanges() called after the loop. How can I update the previously added row in the entity collection without repeatedly calling context.SaveChanges() inside my loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have done it over the past decade or so, but I have used Microsoft Word's Mail Merge to create the SQL statement that I needed (SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE) for each line in an Excel sheet. Once I got the long SQL statement in text I simply copy-paste it into the console and the statement was executed and the job was done. I am confident that there are better ways of doing this but it worked at the time with limited knowledge but a need. This answer is probably in the category "*don't try this at work, but it is fine to do it at home if it does the job*".